# QGIS Processing Plugin works but opens new QGIS with critical warnings

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I've developed a QGIS Processing plugin that takes an input of tweet IDs, gets their metadata and then extracts their coordinates to plot points. It works but it also causes a new QGIS window to open and displays warnings like:

> CRITICAL Invalid Data Source : /-c is not a valid or recognized data source.
>
> CRITICAL Invalid Data Source : /from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import main;main(49) is not a valid or recognized data source.

Any idea what I can do to stop a new QGIS from opening given the algorithm works as intended? I thought it might have to do with it not being thread-safe, however, I believe I have returned `FlagNoThreading` correctly unless I missed something.

My code:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsFeatureSink, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsProcessing, QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessingParameterFile, QgsProcessingParameterString, QgsProcessingParameterCrs, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink, QgsProcessingFeedback)
from qgis import processing

from twarc.client2 import Twarc2, expansions
import json
from twarc_csv import CSVConverter
import os
import pandas as pd

class HydrateGeoTweetsAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    
    #reference parameters for calling alogorithm
    CRS = 'CRS'
    TOKEN = 'TOKEN'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
    INPUT = 'INPUT'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

        #importing csv of tweet IDs
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFile(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input Tweet CSV file'),
                extension='csv'
            )
        )
        #specify users Twitter bearer token
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString(
            self.TOKEN,
            self.tr('Input your Twitter API Bearer Token')
        ))
        #specify desired CRS of tweet points
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterCrs(
                self.CRS, self.tr('Desired CRS of points')
            )
        )
        #output point layer
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer'),
                QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint
            )
        )

    #flagging anything not thread safe 
    def flags(self):
        return super().flags() | QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading
        
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        bearer_token = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.TOKEN, context)
        crsgeometry = self.parameterAsCrs(parameters, self.CRS, context)
        #specifying users file paths to the path of input
        filePathFile = self.parameterDefinition('INPUT').valueAsPythonString(parameters['INPUT'], context)
        in_path = os.path.dirname(filePathFile[1:]) + '/'
        
        #asking user to specify a file to import        
        tweet_idsFile = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, self.INPUT, 
 context)
        #token you need to request from twitter API
        t = Twarc2(bearer_token=bearer_token)

        #iterating over CSV using twarc to hydrate each Tweet ID
        with open(tweet_idsFile, "r") as f:
            #splitting tweets into sepearate lines
            all_tweet_ids = f.read().splitlines()
        #calling twarc to hydrate split tweet IDs
        lookup = t.tweet_lookup(tweet_ids=all_tweet_ids)

        with open((in_path + "tweet_results.jsonl"), "w+") as f:
            #for each page of retrieved metadata
            for page in lookup:
                #flatten into a single line
                result = expansions.flatten(page)
                #for each tweet in results
                for i, tweet in enumerate(result):
                    #write each tweet meatadata as a new line in jsonl
                    f.write(json.dumps(tweet) + "\n")

        #converting JSONL to CSV to get coordinate pairs
        with open((in_path + "tweet_results.jsonl"), "r") as infile:
            with open((in_path + "output.csv"), "w") as outfile:
                convert = CSVConverter(infile, outfile, json_encode_all=True, json_encode_lists=True, json_encode_text=False, inline_referenced_tweets=True, allow_duplicates=False, batch_size=1000)
                convert.process()
        feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

        #twitter records coordinates under a single column, while QGIS expects two columns, Pandas here splits the coordinate values
        df = pd.read_csv(in_path + 'output.csv')
        df[['geoy', 'geox']] = df['geo.coordinates.coordinates'].str.split(',', 1, expand=True)
        df.geoy = df.geoy.str.replace(' ', '')
        df.geox = df.geox.str.replace(' ', '')
        df['geoy']=df['geoy'].str[1:]
        df['geox']=df['geox'].str[:-1]
        df.to_csv(in_path + 'edited.csv')
        
        #plotting points based on coordinate fields   
        processing_layer_result = processing.run("native:createpointslayerfromtable",
                {'INPUT':in_path + 'edited.csv',
                'XFIELD':'geoy',
                'YFIELD':'geox',
                'ZFIELD':'',
                'MFIELD':'',
                'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crsgeometry),
                'OUTPUT':parameters['OUTPUT']}, is_child_algorithm=True,
                context=context,
                feedback=feedback)
        
        #returning the output
        dest_id = ['OUTPUT']
        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
            


    #defining name of algorithm
    def name(self):

        return 'Hydrate and plot tweets'

    #User displayed name
    def displayName(self):

        return self.tr(self.name())

    #group the alogrithm belongs to
    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to. This string
        should be localised.
        """
        return self.tr(self.groupId())

    #ID of algorithm group
    def groupId(self):

        return ''

    #plugin type
    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    #create an instance of the algorithm
    def createInstance(self):
        return HydrateGeoTweetsAlgorithm()
```

Comment: After, `in_path = os.path.dirname(filePathFile[1:]) + '/'`, can you insert `print(in_path)`? What does it return?

Comment: @ThomasG77 I have no idea how to do this, nothing is returned after executing the processing plugin with the print statement and remote attaching to debug isn't working either

Comment: It seems to be picking up the right path anyway, manually importing using create points from the table gives: `'INPUT' : '/Users/Jen/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/HydrateGeoTweets-master/SampleTweetIDs/edited.csv''` On the other hand my processing plugin gives: `'INPUT' : '/Users/Jen/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/HydrateGeoTweets-master/SampleTweetIDs/2021_august31_september1.csv'` The difference in filenames is just post-processed CSV vs pre-processing.

Comment: So it seems to have something to do with multiprocessing, but I have no clue why and how to fix it